# Refreshing collection in the parent viewmodel by invoking delegate in child viewmodel results in NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

There is a DataGrid where every row has Save/Delete buttons. ItemSource of the given DataGrid is the following collection

```
private ObservableCollection<OrderViewModel> orders;
public ObservableCollection<OrderViewModel> Orders
{
    get
    {
        if(orders == null)
        {
            orders = GetOrders();
        }
        return orders;
    }
    set
    {
        if (orders == value) return;

        orders = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

`OrderViewModel` has the following constructor

```
private readonly Action _refreshOrdersHandler;

public OrderViewModel(Action refreshOrdersDelegate)
{
    _refreshOrdersHandler = refreshOrdersDelegate;
}
```

And it's used to initialize collection with the data received from the database

```
public ObservableCollection<OrderViewModel> GetOrders()
{
    try
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<OrderViewModel>(_dataAccess.GetOrdersOpen()
        .Select(o => new OrderViewModel(RefreshOrders)
        {
            Order = o,
        }).ToList());
    }
    catch (SqlException)
    {
        Plugin.LogMessagesCollection.AddLogMessage("Failed to load orders",
            LogMessageType.Error);
        return new ObservableCollection<OrderViewModel>();
    }
}
```

Every time when Save/Delete method is performed in `OrderViewModel` (on button click) there is a need to refresh `Orders` collection so `_refreshOrdersHandler.Invoke()` is called.

where `RefreshOrders`

```
private void RefreshOrders()
{
    Orders = GetOrders();
}
```

However calling `RefreshOrders` upon invoking delegate in the child viewmodel gives the following error: `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` in the `OnPropertyChanged` handler which is defined in the `ObservableObject` class which is inherited by both of the viewmodels

```
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

How is it possible that the given exception is thrown if there is a null check on `PropertyChanged`?

Comment: Seems like there might be more to your story, like a separate thread perhaps? Scenario seems very simple but the way you went about it is a bit complicated. Have you tried using a SelectedItem and put logic for updating there. Also why would you need to refresh the list since UI has the most up to date data?

Comment: A few seconds after I had posted it I have realized that as you said I should just change it to bind to `SelectedItem` as I always do that to accomplish things like that. However I am still not sure why the described method didn't work. There are no other threads created.

Comment: Now looking at that, isn't this way a better way to follow Single Responsibility Principle?

Comment: Your commands should be in the parent viewmodel - the same viewmodel contains Orders rather than in each order. Then you don't need to refresh orders. You remove whatever you're deleting. If you want SRP then you would arguably need to inject delegates for your commands. That can quickly make things a lot more complicated compared to closures capturing variables.  It makes the logic isolated for testing so it's moq friendly though. I would pass the Order to the command rather than use selected item, personally.

Comment: Building on Andy's comment, your orders are more of a Model rather than ViewModel. They represent data in db. Your parent VM should take care of commands. Otherwise you could have 1000 records in there and each one of them will have the same 3 commands, times 1000. But if they are in parent VM then you have 3 commands regardless of how many orders there are.